# glBufferData generating GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm going through the [OGLdev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial32/tutorial32.html) tutorials, and I'm getting stuck on getting Vertex Array Objects to work. Here's the relevant code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[POS_VB]);

FloatBuffer posBuf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(positions.size() * 3);
for (Vector3f v : positions) {
    posBuf.put(v.toFloatArray());
}
posBuf.flip();

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`POS_VB` is 1, and `positions` is an ArrayList filled with the positions (as `Vector3f`'s) of the mesh. `v.toFloatArray()` just returns a float array with the members of the vector.

Having checked the code where `glGetError()` starts generating anything other than 0, I've found that this line:

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

is the culprit. However, checking the documentation, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is only generated when the first parameter is set to the reserved value (0). This is obviously not the case, so what's happening here?

Comment: And `buffers[POS_VB]` is a valid buffer id?

Comment: When I use `glGenBuffers` on my `IntBuffer`, and then copy the values from that buffer into `buffers[]` I get all 0s. Is that supposed to happen? @RetoKoradi

Comment: Nope, 0 is not a valid buffer id. Looks like your problem is in that area.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that I'm using that function wrong; I generated the buffers individually and that turned out fine. Thanks! @RetoKoradi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two conditions where `glBufferData()` will trigger a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. This is from the OpenGL 4.5 spec:

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated by BufferData if zero is bound to target.
>
> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if the BUFFER_IMMUTABLE_STORAGE ﬂag of the buffer object is TRUE.

The second error condition only applies to OpenGL 4.4 and later, where immutable buffers can be allocated with `glBufferStorage()`.

Therefore, the only logical explanation in your case is that you have 0 bound for `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. You're binding the buffer in the first line of the posted code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[POS_VB]);
```

This means that `buffer[POS_VB]` is 0 at this point. Buffer ids need to be generated with `glGenBuffers()` before being used. It looks like either you missed the `glGenBuffers()` call, or used it improperly.